Sharing Data from Databricks to Snowflake Customers – Delta Sharing or Other Options?
I’m currently looking for the best way to share data from Databricks with customers using Snowflake. Are there any suggestions on how Snowflake can read data shared via Delta Sharing from Databricks? If not, are there alternative mechanisms for sharing tables from Databricks with Snowflake customers?
I’ve also read about Lakehouse Federation and querying data from Snowflake to Databricks. For those who have experience sharing data between Databricks and Snowflake, what has worked best for you? Any documentation would be appreciated.
